# Is the IPN working?, because the IPN simulator is not working and i am trying with a real transaction but i can't receive any notification

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

Is the IPN working?, because the IPN simulator is not working and i am trying with a real transaction but i can't receive any notification in my listener.php

I have been trying with the IPN simulator to send a notification to my listener.php but apparently it is not working, it is throwing this error "window.moment is not a function" and apparently paypal is working on it.
For the previous reason I have been trying with real transactions, but there is no response from the IPN.

I am trying to put the answer to a txt file

```
$raw=file_get_contents('php://input');
file_put_contents("testP.txt", $raw);

$doc = fopen(filename:"testP.txt", mode:"w");
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    fwrite($doc, string:"$key => $value \r\n");
}
fclose($doc);
```

There is no result and I would like to know if the IPN is working or I am doing something wrong, because I only created the paypal buttons and added in the advanced variables the url of my listener.php as the paypal documentation says

Comment: I also noticed the bug in the IPN simulator, very annoying. I had to create a version of my client that uses the Sandbox.

Comment: Yes, the simulator is not working but I am trying with real transactions, do you think it does not work in that case either?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't working. I contacted PayPal support and got the following reply:

> We have reported this problem and are already working on it.
>
> Try again later or feel free to ask me about the status.

I will get back to this thread if it starts working again.